# How can I get my Excel macro to interface with CATIA V6?

Tags: catia

I created an Excel macro that uses Excel data to create geometry in CATIA V5. I am now trying to figure out how to make it work with CATIA V6. I don't know the commands to make it find the part I have open in CATIA. I have not been able to find any example code for a CATIA V6 Macro. Does any one know where to go to find an example CATIA V6 macro?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of getting hold of an object in session, and it depends on what language you're using to write the macro. What you need to do is drill down to the 3DRepresenation of the active object using BrowseInstances. Are you using the RACE environment for V6 or CSE? There's a lot of variety between them, and it also depends if you're after the 3D geometry of the object or the properties.

Comment: In the CATIA V5 version, I used VBA. I am not familiar with RACE or CSE.